# InvalidCastException when instancing generic type

Tags: c#, exception, generics, casting

The following code gives me an `InvalidCastException`, stating that I can't cast from source to destination type in the `foreach` loop. I've tried passing multiple different generic collections through the method and I always get this error. I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void WriteDataListToFile<T>(T dataList, string folderPath, string fileName) where T : IEnumerable, ICollection
{    
     //Check to see if file already exists
     if(!File.Exists(folderPath + fileName))
     {
         //if not, create it
         File.Create(folderPath + fileName);
     }

     using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + fileName))
     {
         foreach(T type in dataList)
         {
             sw.WriteLine(type.ToString());
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: I am very suppressed you are not getting some other exception. `File.Create(folderPath + fileName);` is wrong, you are opening a `FileStream` and never closing it. `StreamWriter` will create the file if it does not exist, remove your top checking code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`var`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) like this:

```
foreach (var type in dataList)
{
    sw.WriteLine(type.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat. Should have been obvious really. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You `dataList` should be an `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public static void WriteDataListToFile<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataList, string folderPath, string fileName)
{
    //Check to see if file already exists
    if (!File.Exists(folderPath + fileName))
    {
        //if not, create it
        File.Create(folderPath + fileName);
    }

    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + fileName))
    {
        foreach (T type in dataList)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(type.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to type each item inside the list as `T`, but your type constraints force `T` to be `IEnumerable`. I think you want to specify your parameter as `IEnumerable<T>` and to remove the type constraints:

```
public static void WriteDataListToFile<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataList, string folderPath, string fileName) //no type constraints
{
    //your other things
    foreach(T type in dataList)
    {
        sw.WriteLine(type.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try casting your collection within the `foreach` using `Cast<T>`. like this:

```
public static void WriteDataListToFile<T>(T dataList, string folderPath, string fileName) where T : IEnumerable, ICollection
 {    
     //Check to see if file already exists
     if(!File.Exists(folderPath + fileName))
     {
         //if not, create it
         File.Create(folderPath + fileName);
     }

     using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(folderPath + fileName))   
     {
        // added Cast<T>
         foreach(T type in dataList.Cast<T>())
         {
             sw.WriteLine(type.ToString());
         }
     }
}
```